# Not getting debug output for view errors in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is very odd. At the moment, I have some kind of error in a view, but can't see what it is. Also, no debug output in the web server trace.

[image]

The Rails 3.2.2 app is an upgrade from 2.7.10, and I'm using "thin" as my development server. I do get normal debug output when the error occurs in other places.

EDIT: I'm running development, as you can see here:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

EDIT: I can duplicate this behavior by raising an exception in the controller.

Comment: You run this app in development environement ?

Comment: Is there any helpful output in the development.log?

Comment: Change development logger to verbose . Try copying development.rb from a fresh `rails g rails_app`. Make sure its not raising a 500 and rendering the same

Comment: Ahwn about the `config.log_level` setting in `development.rb`?

Comment: Did you change the 500.html content?  That's not the default 500 error message in 3.2.2.

Comment: Can you show some output from the server log? How is the request getting handled?

Comment: @iltempo, the development log gives no indication what the error is. Just shows the 503 being rendered.

Comment: @Sairam Thanks - I used a fresh development.rb - no change.

Comment: I found the problem: For some reason, I had a begin/rescue around the code in a controller, rendering a 503 on an error. There must have been something going on in Rails 2.7 that I was working around. Thank you everyone, for trying to help.

Comment: I recently tried messing up ActionPack with bad code. I saw the same errors. Do you have anything in the logs ? Try removing the gems actionpack, actionmailer and active* and perform a clean install.

Comment: @Dogweather Nice one. You made it hard for us. ;)

Comment: @Dogweather Can you elaborate on the solution? Which file was it exactly? I'm still having the same problem. (I upgraded from 3.2.something to 3.2.3)

Comment: @MarekMiettinen Simply one of my controllers: I had all the code surrounded by a begin / rescue block, and simply rendering a 503 if there was an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check you development.rb and ensure that

`config.consider_all_requests_local = true`

Otherwise exceptions and stack traces will not be shown.

Comment: Yep, it is. I'm going to try to reproduce the problem with clean rails install. I wonder if it's a certain combination of versions of the various pieces (Ruby 1.9.3, thin server, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the files in your ./config directory of your app with those of a clean Rails 3.2 install. They've restructured things pretty significantly and there are often strange errors like this that popup if you don't properly upgrade all the config files.