# Rails 4 exception stack traces don't show in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I'm following the [rails tutorial book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book) and using the [c9.io](https://c9.io) web IDE as I follow the tutorials. While working on my sample application, I noticed that exceptions aren't being shown on the page in while in development mode. Additionally, the exception stack traces aren't being logged in `log/development.log` either. This predicament is making it difficult to debug errors in my code.

**Error from application**
[image]

**Error in `development.log`**

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 116ms (ActiveRecord: 2.3ms)
```

**What I've already tried / researched**

- `config.log_level = :debug` (in config/environments/development.rb)
- `config.consider_all_requests_local       = true`
- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946492/rails-3-2-development-mode-is-not-displaying-the-full-error-page-with-backtrace)
- [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645446/not-getting-debug-output-for-view-errors-in-development-mode)
- [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624208/rails-doesnt-log-tempalte-errors-in-development-mode/17978388#17978388)

**config/environments/development.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
  config.log_level = :debug
end
```

Please keep in mind that I am **not** interested in answers that attempt to find a solution for the exception being thrown. I'm only looking to enable the exception stack traces so that I may debug the problem myself.

### Edit 2/25/2017

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.36.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '3.1.0'
end
```

Comment: which server are you using and how are you running it?

Comment: It's using WEBrick in development. I'm running it with `rails s -b $IP -p $PORT` (`$IP` and `$PORT` are required in the c9.io hosting environment. See: [link](https://docs.c9.io/docs/run-an-application)).

Comment: Did you find a solution? I actually hit the same problem and don't know how to solve it

Comment: This behavior suggests that you might be running your app in production mode. Are you absolutely sure you are running your server in `development` env? The output tab in the c9 IDE should say something like: `Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080` - can you confirm?  I just have successfully set up a minimal rails app on c9 and it's showing exceptions fine - see https://so-36670968-borama.c9users.io/ . Also, at what point of the rails tutorial were you when you realized exceptions are not shown? Can you provide a link to the specific tutorial part?

Comment: Yes, development mode.

        $rails s
        => Booting Puma
        => Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
        => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
        Puma starting in single mode...
        * Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.3.1-p112), codename: Sassy Salamander
        * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
        * Environment: development
        * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000

Comment: It's been a year since I posted this question. I never resolved the issue. I instead set up another development environment on a VM, which seemed to work just fine. Since there appears to be some new interest in the question, I've pulled up the old C9 instance to test some of the suggestions here. I can confirm that the console outputs `Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080` when booting up the app.

Comment: What gems are you using only in development?

Comment: I appended my Gemfile to the end of the post.

Answer (score 11):

Try to update your web-console gem.

```
bundle update web-console
```

Comment: This was my issue, i had version 2.x and after updating to 3.x, all was right with the world again

Comment: Also my issue after updating a Rails 4 app to Rails 5.

Comment: And make sure it is not locked in Gemfile ;)

Comment: Same problem here under Rails 4. I just removed web-console. I never use it. Afterwards the stack trace page was shown.

Answer (score 5):

Meanwhile, I was able to find the source of the problem in my case, though still not the solution.

I'm using the `rollbar-gem` extension to be able to post errors in production, which actually seems to suck up all error logs also in development (even though it has been manually disabled). Thus removing the gem and all code gives me access to my logs again.

I posted an issue on this on the gems page.

Comment: Try to put `rollbar-gem` in `group :production` block in your Gemfile, then it won't be loaded on development.

Comment: Yeah, but you still have to make sure initializer code is only called on `production`, otherwise rails will just refuse to start up

Comment: Maybe just a `if Rails.env.production?...end` surrounding the entire initializer?. EDIT: Maybe a `if defined?(Rollbar)...end` surrounding the entire initializer will be a better practice since it checks if `Rollbar` is loaded, as it only would in production due to Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

You're not running the application in `development`. Rails apps can be run locally with `rails s` (short for `rails server`). Make sure you have `RAILS_ENV` or equivalent set to `development`.

Comment: I run `RAILS_ENV=development rails s` to make sure the server really runs in development mode. Still same result

Comment: Can you confirm it really does? What does `Rails.env` equal?

Comment: It definitely does. When I run it on my production server, it also logs the debugging information I need, including stack trace. So even if it would run in production, it still would be supposed to log the needed data

Comment: On C9, executing `rails s` will result in the following output: `Rails 4.2.2 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into production log (`log/production.log`) on the server or `log/` directory for other logs, for example `log/unicorn.stderr.log` or `log/puma.log`

Comment: It logs perfectly as expected on the production server, but not in development

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions of both 'log/development.log' folder and file to make sure rails can write there.

Answer (score 1):

Try to let just
config.consider_all_requests_local = true (in config/environments/development.rb)

and remove this line
config.log_level = :debug (in config/environments/development.rb)

also, you can try with the gem better errors to see if it fix the problem
https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors

if this doesn't fix it, run a "bundle update" in general, to see if there is a gem that is causing problems

Comment: Nope, no change after both

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your application.html.erb file. It should provide you more details

```
<%= debug(params)%>
```

Comment: Getting more details may provide the answer, but this should be a comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, just putting config.consider_all_requests_local = true did make puma show all of errors and full backtrace.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use another way to show errors instead of use the default of Rails.

I caught the same problem and tried everything, but the gem better_errors saved the day.

In your Gemfile you can use

```
group :development, :test do # I use that only in dev
  gem "better_errors"
  # dependency
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end
```

Comment: Worth noting, I had the same issue as the OP on Rails 5, and it was caused by an outdated version of `binding_of_caller`. Upgrading that fixed the fault for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error in a Rails 4 app migrated to Rails 5 app.

Running WEBrick on dev mode and `config.consider_all_requests_local = true`.
Turns out the gem 'web-console'; Using 'bundle update web-console' does not work if the Gemfile is a specific version. So I have to manually change it and update.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved for me by adding

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

to my controllers. Solution found in [this Rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11063#issuecomment-25944482).